# How to put marker on android map location?

Tags: android, google-maps, location, google-maps-android-api-2

After I find this `Location mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();` how can I add a marker to that that location?

Making a marker like
 `MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))`
requires a `position` object, is there a way that I can retrieve a `position` from the `Location` object? or is this done in some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getLatitude()` and `getLongitude()` of the [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html) class which will return double which by then you can pass it in your `new LatLong` constructor.

**sample:**

```
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()))
```